# Contax tvs I: blurry pictures even though focus lock is on

Tags: film, 35mm, manual-focus, contax

iso 400 on autofocus lock and P

[image: contaxtvsi]

[image: contaxtvsi]

[image: contax tvsi]

Answer (score 2):

There's more to getting sharp photos than accurate focus. The shutter speed needs to be fast enough to mitigate against any movement of your hands. Your sample photos show that light levels are low - probably the camera is compensating for the low light by setting a long shutter speed - too long to handhold. You either need to add more light to the scene (by using flash), or steady the camera on something (a tripod for example), or use a faster, more sensitive film.

Realistically though, film just does not perform well in low light conditions - digital is much better. Possibly the best solution overall is to just save your film photos for daylight.

Comment: Thank you I really appreciate you answering. I will definitely try a tripod and look into shutter speed. Would you recommend trying different film? Lower or higher ISO?

Comment: @DianaRivas If you use a tripod, combine it with the self-timer (assuming the camera has that feature) - it means you don't even touch the camera at the moment the photo is taken - which should keep the camera steadier still. ISO 400 is a good general purpose film - if you want something more sensitive (i.e. works better is low light), then you need a higher ISO film... however, that comes with trade-offs... the pictures will be grainier (and the film might be more expensive and harder to find).

Comment: Your camera manual is here: [https://www.cameramanuals.org/contax/contax_tvs.pdf](https://www.cameramanuals.org/contax/contax_tvs.pdf). It seems that the only exposure modes on this camera are Program AE and Aperture-priority AE. In order to encourage the camera to use as fast a shutter speed as possible, you need to shoot in Aperture-priority mode, with the aperture set as wide as possible.

Comment: The mirror shot may actually be missed focus. The most in-focus part of the photo is the wall at the same distance as the mirror. The camera's AF sensor may have detected the mirror or wall (which has two high contrast colors meeting at a horizontal line) and focused on it.